# How to solve the problem on allegation by the assumption?

Tags: soft-question, arithmetic

Question:

" The average marks of the students in four sections A,B,C,D together is 60 %. The average marks of the students of A,B,C,D individually are 45 %,50 %,72% and 80 % respectively. If the average marks of the students of the sections A and B together is 48 % and that of the students of B nd C together is 60 % . What is the ratio of number of students in sections A and D ?"

Doubt:
"I admit that the average of the values of A and D is equal to that of B and C. However that requires us to have a constraint and that is the weights of A,B,C,D all of them should be one. If the weight of even a single class is not one then this assumption is not going to work. However that is what the solution in my book assumes and that is what I am having doubts with. A guidance about the essence of the assumption is most welcome."

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the average of the values of $A$ and $D$ is equal to that of $B$ and $C$ is not an assumption, it is a consequence of the problem formulation. In the way I understand the problem, I disagree with the statement that this fact requires all the weights to be equal to $1$. The question could have specified that the weights given to the grades was different for different sections and the weighted average of the grades in sections $A$ and $D$ would still be equal to the weighted average of the grades in $B$ and $C$:

Letting $n_X$ be the known number of students in section $X$, $g_{X_k}$ the grade of student $k$ in section $X$, $w_X$ the known weight given to the grades in section $X$ and $g_X = \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n_X} w_X g_{X_k}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n_X} w_X}$ the weighted average grade of the students in section $X$, the equations necessary to solve the problem would be

$$
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n_A} w_A g_{A_k} + \sum_{k=1}^{n_B} w_B g_{B_k}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n_A} w_A + \sum_{k=1}^{n_B} w_B} = \dfrac{n_Aw_Ag_A + n_Bw_Bg_B}{n_Aw_A + n_Bw_B} &= 48\\\\
\dfrac{n_Bw_Bg_B + n_Cw_Cg_C}{n_Bw_B + n_Cw_C} &= 60\\\\
\dfrac{n_Aw_Ag_A + n_Bw_Bg_B + n_Cw_Cg_C + n_Dw_Dg_D}{n_Aw_A + n_Bw_B + n_Cw_C + n_Dw_D} &= 60
\end{align}
$$

With the known values $g_A = 45$, $g_B = 50$, $g_C = 72$, and $g_D = 80$, we obtain the solutions

$$
n_Aw_A = \dfrac{2}{3}n_Bw_B\\
n_Cw_C = \dfrac{5}{6}n_Bw_B\\
n_Dw_D = \dfrac{1}{2}n_Bw_B\\
$$

It follows that the average of the grades in A and D is equal to the average of the grades in B and C, regardless of the (non-zero) weights used, because they can both be written in terms of $n_Bw_B$.